# How do get binary code from png on uses javascript

Tags: javascript, binary, png

How do get binary code from png on uses javascript?

Is there methods for getting binary code?

Comment: Binary code for a image ? with js huh ? Clarify what u want

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the actual PNG encoded data, then, no, it's not possible.

But of you want to access the pixel data, you can draw the image to a [`<canvas>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas) and access the individual pixels there.

Also this is only possible with an image from your server. If you want to access an image provided by a user you'll need to upload it to first.

Answer (score 0):

You could use FileReader for local files on user's computer:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader